# How to populate 'Available' multi-picklist side

Tags: picklist, dynamic-picklist

I created a multi picklist field in my opportunity object. In the trigger I created I call the following:

```
BCAccountID_test__c= 'FIRST VALUE' + ';' + 'SECOND VALUE';
```

but those two values are then available to the "Selected" part of the multi-picklist, instead of the 'Available' value. (see attached screenshot).

[image]

I want to initialise the "Available" side of the multi-picklist. 
Can you help?

Thank you .
GC

Answer (score 0):

To make a value Available to the selection, you need to add that value in the field directly. In trigger, we give the selected value.

Go to that field> Click on New and then add values.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi , but is there a way to populate that dynamically as the values can change. The 'First value' 'Second Value' values were to simplistic. What I need to do is to populate it dynamically with different values that are different depending on the account.

Comment: @GiancarloAmati, unfortunately, that's not possible.